# How can I get Doxygen to sort member functions alphabetically by name?

Tags: function, doxygen, member, alphabetical

I'm seeing this in my output code:

```
void shift_left()
void reassign(...)
void add_last()
void multiply_by_scalar()
```

These functions are public members of a class. This occurs regardless of whether I select `SORT_MEMBER_DOCS` and/or `SORT_BRIEF_DOCS` to be true.

Is there any way to get these functions into alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible.

I suggest you read their manual on [reporting bugs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports) and if none of the other sorting bug reports for Doxygen in their issue tracker are a duplicate of what you're experiencing, feel free to file a new bug report.

Comment: I thought this 12 year-old bug might be my issue:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153381

but it's about inherited members. I'm having issues even in the original class, and with a much later version. It might be related to sectioning.

Not sure I want to report a bug if they don't bother fixing 12 year-old ones, though...